# Subselect in a Join - Problem

Tags: mysql, sql, join, derived-table

I've a little Problem with a statement:

```
SELECT 
    p1.Modell_nr, 
    p1.ProductID,
    p2.count_modlieffarbe_vl,
    concat(p1.Modell_nr,'_',p1.LiefFarbe) as modfarb_id1
FROM produkte as p1
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT p2.ProductID as tester,
       count(*) as count_modlieffarbe_vl
       FROM produkte as p2 
       WHERE p2.Vl>p2.vl_min
       group by p2.Modell_nr, p2.LiefFarbe
) as count_modlieffarbe_vla ON p1.ProductID = tester
```

... it works without error-message. ... but get only Modell_nr, ProductID and modfarb_id1 as cols in my results. Why I dont see count_modlieffarbe_vl in my results?

Comment: I'd have expected an error for referencing a table alias in the derived table you're LEFT JOINing to.

Answer (score 1):

I would say becouse it isn't in p2 table. Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT 
p1.Modell_nr, 
p1.ProductID,
count_modlieffarbe_vla.count_modlieffarbe_vl,
concat(p1.Modell_nr,'_',p1.LiefFarbe) as modfarb_id1
FROM produkte as p1
LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT p2.ProductID as tester,
count(*) as count_modlieffarbe_vl
FROM produkte as p2 
WHERE p2.Vl>p2.vl_min
group by p2.Modell_nr, p2.LiefFarbe
) as count_modlieffarbe_vla ON p1.ProductID = tester
```

**count_modlieffarbe_vla.count_modlieffarbe_vl** is the key.

Comment: youre right, had the same structure bevore ... but it seems addional errors somewhere else .... THANX!